# Get translated data from twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j API to stream twitter data, but there is a lot of data not in english.

I can translate the tweets on the UI but is there a way to get the translated text using the API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter's APIs offer no direct translation services. You will need to use an external service (which is exactly what Twitter does via the UI)

Comment: Is there any proof, is it written somewhere?

Comment: No, but I work at Twitter, and I can tell you this is how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any translation api's from google, aws, unlabel. Feed the twitter data to these translation streaming api's and you have desired output.